# EntityCollection as parameter in a method

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, entitycollection

I am trying to write a code where EntityCollection is the parameter of the method
but I don't know what is the proper coding

is there someone who can help me about this?

here is the sample code

```
 //by the way, this is a wrong coding, I am just showing you, what is the thing that I want to do...
private void sampleMethod(EntityCollection a)
{
   if (a.ToList().Count == 0)
   {
      //body
   }
}
```

and when I call it, this is what it looks like

```
sampleMethod(employee.EducationalBackground);
```

Comment: I can't understand what you are looking for... what do you mean for proper coding?

Comment: a correct data type/class for example "employee.EducationalBackrground", so I can use it as a parameter in a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a little difficult to understand but I suppose you're looking for something like this:

```
private void sampleMethod(EntityCollection<Employee> employees)
{
   foreach(var employee in employees)
   {
      // do something with every employee.EducationalBackground
   }
}
```

Search for "c# Generics" for info about the `EntityCollection<Employee>`.

Search for "linq" for info about how to work with collections.